# External display flickers after upgrade on a Lenovo ThinkVision L2440p

Tags: 11.04, xorg, display

I used ubuntu 10.10 so far and I connected my Lenovo Thinkpad 420 via VGA with my display Lenovo ThinkVision L2440p without any problems. Since I upgraded (it was not a fresh install) to ubuntu 11.04, my external display is flickering.

Any idea how I could solve the problem?

Thanks in adavance!

Answer (score 1):

many people has this problem with the lenovo  I guess you have Nvidia card
try to install the new nvidia driver and see how it goes you can download it from nvidia website. instructions to install can be found here try both but I guess the second is the best:

http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/02/how-to-install-nvidia-drivers-manually-in-ubuntu/

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/howto-install-nvidia-drivers-manually-on-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-lynx.html

this problem is because of graphic card. and hopefully it maybe fixed by the newest driver from nvidia which is released in 20 of April or so good luck

Comment: Hi nadeem, I do have the second generation of SandyBridge CPU and thus an integrated GPU. I don't have a dedicated graphic card.